# Is it possible to run bash shells in a Smalltalk Workspace?

Tags: bash, shell, smalltalk, workspace

I want to do all my work in customisable desktop. Smalltalk seems to have a customisable, graphic, workspace, but I need my bash shells as well.

Is it possible to run bash shells in a Smalltalk Workspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a terminal emulator implementation for Squeak at [Ian's site](http://www.squeakvm.org/unix/goodies.html#html/goodies.m4.2.0). This probably needs a bit of cleanup to work in a current version, but it may be your best starting point.